# When making a cross-domain ajax request, my data gets lost

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm making the following cross-domain post, which hits my Rails app no problem. I get a response back, and it is the response I expect. Except that the "weight: 20" has not been taken into account by my app. I am using CORS to make the request, and in particular I am using the [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) gem.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:3000/australia_post_api_connections",
  type: "GET",
  data: { weight: 20 },
  dataType: 'json',
  crossDomain: true,
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("success");
    $('#shipping-calculator').html(data);

  }
}).fail(function() { console.log("fail") })
  .always(function() { console.log("always") })
  .complete(function() { console.log("complete") });
```

Am I making a very simple mistake in my JSON, or am I failing to include some CORS related stuff? This [tutorial](http://leopard.in.ua/2012/07/08/using-cors-with-rails/) mentions `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Request-Headers`. Might that have something to do with it?

Thanks

z.

Comment: I just tried curl -i to hit the same resource, but appending "?weight=20" and that worked. So I suspect this is a CORS thing that I don't quite understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try appending the weight:20 tot he url so it looks like this 
    "http://localhost:3000/australia_post_api_connections?weight=20"
or you could do this to the data

```
data:  JSON.stringify({weight:20})
```

Comment: Yeah it turns out I was doing the data wrong. When I removed the "dataType" line, everything worked. :)